# Combining PDF's and their TOC

Tags: hyperref, pdf

I have three .tex files that get compiled fine using polyglassia & xelatex packages. When I combine these three tex files in one tex file, it exceeds the memory due to a lot of special fonts used in them. So I ended up compiling them separately. As a result, I have three PDF outputs that contain hyperlinked pages to their TOC, and hyperlinked sections in TOC. So, there are three PDF's, thus three Table of Contents for each PDF.

How do I combine these PDF's preserving hyperlinks as well as having one TOC file [preferably in a single multi-column page]?

Comment: Have you tried increasing the memory for the runs of the files?

Comment: No I haven't. There were some instructions how to do for Mac/TeXLive, but not for MikTeX on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

I suppose you are getting `TeX capacity exceeded` error. To overcome that you can increase the memory allocated as suggested by @Martin:

**For MiKTEX:**

1. Open a DOS command prompt window (execute ‘cmd.exe’ via ‘Start’ → ‘Run’).
2. At the DOS prompt, enter `initexmf --edit-config-file=latex`
3. Type `main_memory=10000000` into the editor window that opens, save the file and quit  the editor.
4. To rebuild the format, enter `initexmf --dump=latex` at the DOS prompt
5. Repeat steps 2–4 with config files `pdflatex` and `xelatex`

For the sake of completeness, I add these particulars for Texlive also.

**For TEX Live:**

1. Find the configuration file ‘texmf.cnf’ by means of
   `kpsewhich texmf.cnf` at the shell prompt in a terminal.
2. As Root, open the file in your favourite text editor, scroll to the
   `main_memory` entry and change it to the value given above; save and
   quit.
3. Rebuild the formats by
   `fmtutil-sys --byfmt latex` and 
   `fmtutil-sys --byfmt pdflatex` and 
   `fmtutil-sys --byfmt xelatex`

Comment: Hi. I did exactly how you told here. However, the capacity has decreased from 247 pages [inputs] to 228 pages. Any idea why?

Comment: From here I am not in a position to guess any thing as I don't have any information on your files. Sorry. Generally this will increase the memory allocation.

Comment: I tried to use main_memory=500000000 instead of main_memory=10000000, cmd couldn't proceed with initexmf --dump=latex command. Then I saved and continued with main_memory=500000000 anyway. This time Texworks gave me an error regarding the memory problem.

Answer (score 0):

Consider merging the pdf files after you've generated them from LaTeX with pdftk
(http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/) or some other pdf manipulation tool.

If it can't get the TOC right you might be able to hack a TOC (perhaps with `\includeonly`) and merge it too.